# Where did Aquinas find this gloss?

Tags: exegesis, reference-request, isaiah, summa-theologica

The following passage occurs in Aquinas's *Summa Theologica* ([Supp 91.3](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/aquinas/summa.XP_Q91_A3.html)):

> A gloss on Isaiah 30:26, "The light of the moon shall be as the light
> of the sun," says: "**All things made for man's sake deteriorated at his
> fall, and sun and moon diminished in light**." This diminishment is ...

What exactly or who exactly is Aquinas quoting from here (the **bold** text)? Does this work still exist? And is there a general way to find out where these "glosses" are coming from?

Comment: The "gloss" is a collection made from interlinear notes by scribes in Scripture. The two main ones are the glossa ordinara and the magna glossatura (Peter Lombard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In St. Thomas Aquinas's works, the Gloss is the [*Glossa Ordinaria*](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/06586a.htm#section5).